# DBEAVER: SQL error or missing database (near ",": syntax error)

Tags: sqlite, bulk-insert

I'm using [DBeaver](http://dbeaver.jkiss.org/) (because [Base](http://menial.co.uk/base/) only works on OS X) to work with an `SQLite` database. When I attempt to execute the following query, I get the error message 'SQL error or missing database (near ",": syntax error)', even though I've specified the database and table:

```
INSERT INTO `contacts`.`contacts` (`fname`, `sname`, `dob`) VALUES ('MTN', 'Account', NULL), ('A', 'Person', -20456000), ('Local', 'Police', NULL), ...;
```

`contacts` is the database, containing a table named `contacts` with the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `contacts` (
    `cid` INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `fname` TEXT NULL,
    `sname` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `dob` INTEGER NULL
);
```

I can use the <kbd>+</kbd> button to insert rows, but I'd prefer to perform bulk inserts.

I've already looked at the SQLite INSERT documentation and it looks exactly the same as MySQL's, so I don't see why it's having a hissy fit.

Comment: Does SQLite also use those dreaded backticks?

Comment: If it doesn't, I don't see why not.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Only for compatibility with MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite allows to insert multiple rows with one statment, but only in version 3.7.11 or later.

Apparently, your JDBC SQLite driver is several years out of date.